# JUnit test parametrizado añade un espacio en blanco al valor Expected

Tags: java, junit, test

estoy intentando crear un test con JUnit4, es un test basico que lo unico que tiene q hacer es comprobar si la posicion de las arrays son las correctas. Dejo el codigo a continuacion:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {
@Parameter(0)
public TrafficLight Result;
@Parameter(1)
public int t1;
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{new TrafficLight(1),1 },{new TrafficLight(2),2},{new TrafficLight(0),0}};
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
@Test
public void Tests(){
   TrafficLight ClassTrafficLight = new TrafficLight(t1);
   assertEquals(Result,ClassTrafficLight);
}
```

}
En teoria el codigo esta bien, pero cuando se ejecuta el test el resultado es este:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: TrafficLight<green> but was: TrafficLight<green>
Expected :TrafficLight<green> 
Actual   :TrafficLight<green>
<Click to see difference>
```

Como podeis ver el resultado es el mismo, pero no se porque el valor que tiene Expected tiene un espacio al final, el cual no se puede apreciar desde aqui, pero os aseguro que esta alli. Si alguien sabe porque ocurre esto le estaria muy agradecido.

Aqui la solucion por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{new TrafficLight(1),"green" },{new TrafficLight(2),"yellow"},{new TrafficLight(0),"red"}};
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
    @Parameter()
    public TrafficLight t1;
    @Parameter(1)
    public String Result;
    @Test
    public void Tests(){
        assertEquals("Result",Result,t1.status);
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver el problema era que primero habia que poner los parameters, y que que el resultado devuelto sea el atributo status del objeto.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de haber implementado correctamente `TrafficLight.equals()`?

Comment: Si, ya he encontrado el problema, era que le pedia que devolviese un objeto y no un resultado. La solucion era poner abajo los parameter y que el resutado fuese el estado del objeto. dejo el codigo bien escrito en el post principal, por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda.

Comment: Puedes escribir (y aceptar) tu propia respuesta, hace más fáciles para otros usuarios ver cuál es la solución.

Comment: aun no puedo dar como buena mi respuesta, pero bueno alli esta por si alguien la necesita